# CSS blur + border-radius

Tags: css

Can't find the way to apply blur and border-radius to an image togather. What I want to see is blurred image with rounded corners:

[image]

For example, when I try do this like this:

```
.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.inner {
    background-image: url(...);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```

I get not exactly what I wanted, border-radius is not applyed correctly:

[image]

Comment: [Seems to work](https://jsfiddle.net/4hbbdbjt/). Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: Hm, really works. But I noticed that when I scroll down, the rounding disappears. Maybe a bug

Answer (score 4):

Try this...may be it will help you

```html
<div class="outer"><img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8RE5IWXFmmA/T9TQNJr6f1I/AAAAAAAABDw/FC7jbgZocys/s1600/fb-profile.jpg" class="inner" /></div>

<style>
.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.inner {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

We need your entire code, maybe try this:

```
.inner {
    background-image: url(...);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
}
```